# Set an SVG element's parent div to something for getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Is there a way through which I can specifically set the parent div of an element to something in order to get relative values as return from getBoundingClientRect() function. I read that the function gives relative values but for some reason it is not giving relative values for my code :

```
$("svg").one("click", function() {
if(this.id!='main_svg')   {
a1=this.id;
var element=document.getElementById(a1);
var rect=element.getBoundingClientRect();
alert(rect.top);
...
```

Comment: If you want relative values use getBBox() instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you give me an example of it please? Also, which library to use (if any)

Comment: s/getBoundingClientRect/getBBox/ that's all there is to it.

Comment: @RobertLongson can you explain a little if you have a min

Comment: @Arihant replace `rect=element.getBoundingClientRect();` with `rect=element.getBBox();`